# Magento 2 customer login check code not working

Tags: login, customer-session, magento-2.1.9

I was using **magento 2.1.6** previously and there I used

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

Which worked perfectly there and when I upgrade to **Magento 2.1.9**, the code  is not working anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **create** instead of **get**

```
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
```

It should work.